# response message is not displayed after ajax upload file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jsajaxfileuploader

I am new in ajax. I am trying to make a file uploader with ajax in codeigniter. When I upload the file file is uploaded successfully in /uploads folder but response message that is alert or the image view is not working. I have searched several answers of same problem but could not solve it. Please help me to find the problem of code.

**The controller :**

```
 <?php


class AjaxImageUpload extends CI_Controller {


/**
 * Manage __construct
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}


/**
 * Manage index
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('ajaxImageUploadForm', array('error' => '' ));
}


/**
 * Manage uploadImage
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function uploadImage() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = 10240;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo json_encode($error);
    }else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $success = ['success'=>$data['file_name']];
        echo json_encode($success);
    }
}
}


?>
```

**The view file:**

```
<html>


<head>
    <title>Image Upload Example from Scratch</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>


<body>


    <?php echo form_open_multipart('ajax-image-upload/post');?>
    <input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
    <input type="submit" class="upload-image" value="upload" />
    </form>


    <div class="preview" style="display: none;">
       <img src="">

    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

**The ajax :**

```
 $("body").on("click",".upload-image",function(e){
    $(this).parents("form").ajaxForm(options);
});


var options = {
    complete: function(response)
    {
        if($.isEmptyObject(response.responseJSON.error)){
            alert('Image Upload Successfully.');
            $(".preview").css("display","block");
            $(".preview").find("img").attr("src","/uploads/"+response.responseJSON.success);
        }else{
            alert('Image Upload Error.');
        }
    }
};`
```

Comment: Echo json_decode....Not encode

Comment: @SachinAghera - `json_decode()` converts a JSON string to an object or array. How would you echo those? If you want to output json, the OP does it correctly: `echo json_encode($somevar)`.

Comment: Have you check in $success are you get data or not?

Comment: What does _"is not working"_ mean? Error messages in the console? Have you checked the network tab in the browsers development tools to find what the request actually returns?

Comment: I would also recommend to always return the same parameters in your json response. `['error' => {}, 'success' => true]` and just change the values (success: false and populate the errors when there's an error) to fit the response.

Comment: Do *not* echo json_decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(response.responseJSON.success)) {
    alert('Image Upload Successfully.');
    $(".preview").css("display", "block");
    $(".preview").find("img").attr("src", "/uploads/" + response.responseJSON.success);
} else {
    alert('Image Upload Error.');
}
```

Comment: Am I blind? This looks the same as the code posted by OP.